# Why are these loop diagrams involving Goldstone bosons cancelling one another in the zero-momentum limit?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance, electroweak

I have been working with one-loop corrections to certain processes. Let's say, corrections to the $Z\bar{f}f$ vertex. Of, course I need to consider the following diagrams:

[image]

Here $\phi^{\pm}$ is the Goldstone boson that would be eaten by the $W$ boson. I am working in the so-called Feynman-'t Hooft gauge, where $\xi = 1$.

Let's call the triangular diagram $\delta_{\phi \phi}(p^2)$ and the two lower ones with the dressed propagators of the outer fermions $\delta_{\Sigma 1}(p^2)$ and $\delta_{\Sigma 2}(p^2)$. And $p$ denotes the four-momentum of the outer $Z$-boson, since all the corrections are functions of these.

In the limit where $p^2\to 0$ I've noticed that:

$$\delta_{\phi \phi}(0) + \frac{1}{2}\left[\delta_{\Sigma 1}(0) + \delta_{\Sigma 2}(0) \right] = 0$$

My question is: why? Why is this vanishing? Why does it vanish for the Goldstone boson, but not if I had instead a $W$ boson?

This relation looks quite similar to the Ward-Takashi identities in QED for the renormalization counter-terms, I assume it is related, but I have not found any of the literature that mentions this.

PS: why is it necessary to add the $1/2$ factor? I know that when doing this wave-function renormalization what appears in the counter-terms is $Z_\psi^{1/2}$ and not $Z_\psi$, where I assume it stems from, but why should that be included when considering the correction to the complete vertex? I mean, it should simply appear from applying the Feynman rules and doing the loop integral as it is, shouldn't it?

Comment: Prior to asking this question, I did the same computation but in the $\xi$-gauge. I discovered that both amplitudes are completely proportional to the gauge parameter $\xi$ when $p^2 \to 0$. But it seems like this is not the case for the internal $W$ contributions. I guess this should be good enough, right? What is not entirely clear to me, is that the divergent terms are completely gauge independent, why should those vanish too?

Comment: Hint: Adler zeros; Goldstone bosons couple through derivative couplings, *always*, so they decouple at vanishing momenta...

Comment: @CosmasZachos but there is a third diagram I did not include, it is another triangular diagram, with one Goldstone instead of two. This one does not vanish with anything else. Is the Adler zeroes explanation still applicable in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to shadow-box with unseen diagrams and questions. I just gave you a generic background hint...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Do you have reference you have that could help me? This is the first time I've heard about "Adler Zeros"

Comment: Oh, just google it.... [Here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02731779.pdf)... The WP article on Goldstone bosons illustrates the simple point... infinite wavelength excitations....